# PHP/Laravel: Observe IOPS

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, io, debian

As our application includes a lot of files, especially from resources/views/ and vendor/ (588 per request), I want to track the amount of I/Os per request. Furthermore we are requesting data from our own API that is currently hosted on the same server. If possible I also want to include I/Os caused by this as well.

We are using the following setup:

- Laravel, Laravel Homestead (Ubuntu), PHP 7.0, Nginx, Redis, MySQL
- Laravel, Debian 7 (DEV/Test), PHP 7.1, Nginx, Redis, MySQL

So my questions:

1. is there a way to gather the count of total I/Os per page impression?
2. in which way is OPCache able to reduce the number of I/Os, what is optimizable, what is not affected?

Please include the question-number in your comments.

Thank you!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

> there a way to gather the count of total I/Os per page impression?

I do not think there is a way to get the explicit I/O requirements per page from PHP.

> in which way is OPCache able to reduce the number of I/Os, what is optimizable, what is not affected?

OPcache improves PHP performance by storing precompiled script bytecode in shared memory, thereby removing the need for PHP to load and parse scripts on each request.